# Error in trying to push model to huggingface

Tags: git, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

So, I am making a chatbot for discord using google Collaboratory. However whenever, i try to push it on huggingface.co. It does deploy and instead gives me an error. Also, while trying to clone the repo, it's giving me an error **fatal: destination path 'DialoGPT-small-technoblade' already exists and is not an empty directory.**
[The error that is being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uaol.png)

The code I'm using

```
!pip install huggingface_hub
!sudo apt-get install git-lfs
!git config --global user.email "email"
!git config --global user.name "username"

!transformers-cli login
!git clone https://user:...token...@huggingface.co/user/repo
!ls -al

!git lfs install
!git add .
!git commit -m "Initial commit"

!git log
!git push
```

Comment: You have two separate problems, which deserve two separate questions. One is about the pre-push hook permissions, and one is about `git clone`. Your `git clone` is giving you an error because you're telling Git to create a new clone, and then fill it in, in a location where you *already have something* (some files and/or directories) which *would have to be removed first* to accomplish what you asked for. Either remove these yourself if they're not supposed to be in the way, or tell Git to put the clone in a place where it *won't* destroy something first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, all you have to do is delete a folder on your drive to the name of **DialoGPT-Small-Technoblade**.

Otherwise, I don't know. See what the results are if you try it on a VM (For Linux, I recommend VirtualBox)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).